# ASP.NET GridView in Update Panel and GridView Row.Count

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have an ASP.NET GridView that sits in an UpdatePanel. On the GridView i have a OnRowCommand which is used to delete or update rows from the Grid. This all works fine. The rows are being deleted, and the user sees them disappearing from his screen. All as it should. In other cases users use a OnRowCommand to update the quantity field on these rows. That also works fine.

But now, outside of that UpdatePanel there is a button; Process GridView lines. And here comes the problem. After removing all the rows (records) from the GridView, and then clicking on the process button, the code behind still sees GridView.Rows.Count = 1, instead of 0.

Can anyone point me at some info on how to make better use of this combination of UpdatePanel, GridView and button/postback? I'm sure there is a way to handle this so that i dont run into this error.

Some code:

```
 protected void gvLines_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
 {
   //fired from a button, on a grid row which sits in an ASP.NET Update Panel!
   //some db work to delete a line from the grid.
   //bind the grid lines again to correctly see the remaining lines
 }

 protected void btnConfirmOrder_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
   foreach (GridViewRow gvr in gvBasketLines.Rows)
   {
      //when running this code in a button click/postback, 
      //ASP.NET still thinks that the line we just removed still exists.
   }
 }
```

Comment: Does it constantly return 1? Or 1 was the row count prior deletion?

Comment: Can you show some code? OnRowCommand?

Comment: 1 was the count after deletion

Comment: I have updated my question with a simplified piece of code

Answer (score 0):

Use the DataBound event of the GridView to get the row count.